# Is there a way to turn off backlit buttons on Motorola Droid?

Tags: motorola-droid, backlight

The four buttons at the bottom of the Motorola Droid (back,menu,home,search) are backlit when its dark and the phone is unlocked. The brightness of the buttons' back light doesn't adjust with the brightness of the screen, which can be a real problem when I'm using an app at night. Is there any way to turn off or dim these buttons?

Comment: I have the same problem with my HTC Hero and have searched for a solution in the past.  About a month ago I came to the conclusion that there was no easy solution.

Comment: I find this especially annoying when the phone is in clock mode in my dock (Moto Droid, 2.2).

Comment: Good question.  I'm surprised no one has figured this out yet.  Make sure to report back if you find the answer somewhere else because I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [LEDs Hack](http://www.appbrain.com/app/leds-hack-%28root-only%29/net.geekherd.softbuttonshack) app if you've got the root thing going.

Comment: That's no longer available on the Android market.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [Screen Filter](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor) that will allow you to switch the menu button backlight off.